# Query String errada com o uso do prepare. Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Estou com um problema ao construir uma query aqui:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}imagens WHERE categorias LIKE %d limit %s, %s", array('%' . $wpdb->esc_like($var['busca']) . '%', $init, 45));

$registers = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Não retorna nada.

Antes estava assim e listava perfeitamente:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_imagens WHERE categorias LIKE '%".$var['busca']."%' $init,45";

$registers = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

O que tem de errado com a Query do prepare?

Comment: Com o prepare não precisa de um execute não? Tipo: `$wpdb->execute();`

Answer (score 0):

Você utilizou o placeholder `%d` para um parâmetro string, sendo que ele é para inteiros. Utilize o placeholder `%s`.

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}imagens WHERE categorias LIKE %s limit %s, %s", array('%' . $wpdb->esc_like($var['busca']) . '%', $init, 45));

$registers = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você deva executar a query antes de pegar os resultados:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}imagens WHERE categorias LIKE %d limit %s, %s", array('%' . $wpdb->esc_like($var['busca']) . '%', $init, 45));
$sql->execute();
$registers = $sql->get_results();
```